# How to await or rebuild Consumer when data is loaded

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, google-maps-flutter

How do I reload Consumer when data is loaded or await for data to load. I am using Future Provider and everything is rebuilding itself when data is loaded (currentPosition Fetched) and using `circularProgress()` while waiting. But consumer is not rebuilding itself aslo can't use await with consumer package. When I save the code while debugging when it hot reload everything is okay but that's nit a solutiion. I want the consumer auto reload when data is fetched. I am fetching the data to make markers on google_Maps_Flutter

```
body: (currentPosition != null)
        ? Consumer<List<Bar>>(builder: (_, places, child) {
            List.generate(places.length, (index) async {
              print(places.length);
              print(index);
              print(imageUrl(places[index].photoRef));
              List<String> wordList = places[index].name.split(" ");

              bitmapIcon = await customBitmapDescriptor(
                imageUrl: imageUrl(places[index].photoRef),
                title: wordList[0],
              );
              markers = markerService.getBarMarkers(
                places,
                markerIcon: this.bitmapIcon,
              );
              print(markers.isEmpty);
            });
```

Comment: I need more description about currentPosition and other code.

Comment: currentPosition is being fetched by API to gete my location and main thing is places which are fetching from APIS and markers a re being added to that places

Comment: Consumer is used to build a widget with the data provided, not to do future logic with it, I recommend do that logic somewhere else or use FutureProvider instead of consumer and then consume it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setState((){});` to rebuild when data is loaded. Add `setState((){});` where you want to rebuild e.g. if you want to reload when data is loaded in bitmapIcon then add

```
bitmapIcon = await convertImageFileToCustomBitmapDescriptor(
                          imageUrl: imageUrl(places[index].photoRef),
                          title: wordList[0],
                        ).then((value) {
                          setState(() {});
                        });
```

And if you want to reload when data is loaded in marker then use

```
setState(() {
              markers = markerService.getBarMarkers(
                            places,
                            markerIcon: this.bitmapIcon,
                          );
                        });
```

**First Scenario**

```
body: (currentPosition != null)
    ? Consumer<List<Bar>>(builder: (_, places, child) {
        List.generate(places.length, (index) async {
          print(places.length);
          print(index);
          print(imageUrl(places[index].photoRef));
          List<String> wordList = places[index].name.split(" ");

          bitmapIcon =await convertImageFileToCustomBitmapDescriptor(
                          imageUrl: imageUrl(places[index].photoRef),
                          title: wordList[0],
                        ).then((value) {
                          setState(() {});
                        });
          markers = markerService.getBarMarkers(
            places,
            markerIcon: this.bitmapIcon,
          );
          print(markers.isEmpty);
        });
```

**Second Scenario**

```
body: (currentPosition != null)
    ? Consumer<List<Bar>>(builder: (_, places, child) {
        List.generate(places.length, (index) async {
          print(places.length);
          print(index);
          print(imageUrl(places[index].photoRef));
          List<String> wordList = places[index].name.split(" ");

          bitmapIcon = await convertImageFileToCustomBitmapDescriptor(
                          imageUrl: imageUrl(places[index].photoRef),
                          title: wordList[0],
                        );
        if(!isSet){
          setState(() {
                          markers = markerService.getBarMarkers(
                            places,
                            markerIcon: this.bitmapIcon,
                          );
                        });
         }
          print(markers.isEmpty);
        });
```

**Thumbs up if this solution helped**

Comment: First Scenario is throwing some error but yes second Scenario worked for me.

Comment: There is a problem is second scenario. Although it worked but now problem is it is rebuilding again and again because of `setState((){})` after every build

Comment: Add condition like declare any `bool isSet = false;` and then while apply condition and `setState((){});` in it. Like   `if(isSet == false){  setState((){  isSet = true;  markers = markerService.getBarMarkers(places,markerIcon: this.bitmapIcon,);  }  );  }`

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `notifyListener()` you can change the state of a consumer.

Below is a sample code. If You need more let me know.

```js
Consumer<DataProviderClass>(
                builder: (context, portfolioProvider, _) {
                print("state changed");
                
                return RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Press"),
                onPressed : () =>  
                   Provider.of<DataProviderClass(context).fetchData(),
                  );
                }
);


                
                
                
class DataProviderClass with ChangeNotifier{
    fetchData(){
      notifyListener();
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is I want my system automatically rebuild itself on data uploaded